# Convergence of a specific sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to find where the sequence $$a_i = (1+k)(1+2k)(1+3k) \cdots (1+ik)$$ converge. Suppose $k$ is a natural number. Is anyone able to help me with that? I might be nice to have a general function with factorial.

**EDIT :**

For $k=1$, it means $a_i=(1+i)!$. This is the straightforward case. What about $k=50$? I am not sure of the answer

Comment: That sequence is _strictly increasing_, and probably for every choice of $k \neq \frac {-1}m$ (take $k=1$ for instance - $a_i$ = (i+1)!$). So...

Comment: I understand your point, but is there a general function? I don't know something like $a_i = (1+ik)^i$. It is much more elegant

Comment: Have you tried taking $k=1$ and computing a few terms to see what happens?

Comment: @LucasHenrique For $k=1$, it means $a_i = (1+i)!$. This is the straightforward case. What about $k=50$? I am not sure of the answer

Comment: @J.Doe For any $k>1$ implies $a_i>(1+i)!$. What you can say about that?

Comment: @J.Doe If $k=0$, then $a_i=1$, so it converges. If $k=-1$, then $a_i=0$, so it converges.

Comment: @J.Doe If $k<-2$, then you can show $a_i$ diverges

Comment: @DiegoMath To be honest, I don't have experience with maths. I am a day trader in life with a college background in maths.

Comment: @DiegoMath I changed the question. Suppose $k$ is a natural number instead. I don't want to consider negative number

Comment: @J.Doe In this case, the only number such $a_i$ converges is $k=0$ (If you consider $0\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Is there a general solution with factorial annotation instead of writing $a_i = (1+k)(1+2k)(1+3k) \cdots (1+ik)$ each time. The general solution for $k=1$ is simple $a_i = (1+i)!$. What about $k>2$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$a_i=(1+k)(1+2k)(1+3k) \cdots (1+ik)>k\cdot(2k)\cdot\ldots\cdot(ik)=i!k^i.$$
By other hand, for any $k\geq1$

$i!k^i\geq i!\to\infty.$

Since $a_i>i!k^i$, then $a_i$ diverges for all natural $k\geq1$.

**PLUS:** If you consider $0\in\mathbb{N}$, then, for $k=0$, we have
$$a_i=\underbrace{1\cdot1\cdot\ldots\cdot1}_{\text{$i$ times}}=1^i=1.$$
Thus, $a_i\to1$, then it converges.

Comment: Don't think your answer is right. Check for $k=2$ and $i=3$. I am looking to something similiar to your answer

Comment: @J.Doe I fixed the answer, please check out.

Comment: This is not really what I want. I am looking for a factorial representation for $a_i$. I know it is not convergent for $k > 1$